# app-engine error due to import _multiprocessing

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, multiprocessing, google-cloud-endpoints

I create an app-engine endpoint api, which I am loading using GoogleAppengineLauncher. The api launches fine. But when I try to load api explorer for testing, I get an error due to the line `from multiprocessing import Process`. My research led me [to this site](http://www.alishabdar.com/2009/09/26/fixing-the-multiprocessing-error-while-developing-for-appengine/). But that's not working for me. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    import _multiprocessing
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 861, in load_module
    raise ImportError
ImportError
INFO     2013-03-25 23:46:32,229 server.py:528] "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2013-03-25 23:46:32,229 server.py:528] "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis HTTP/1.1" 500 60
```

Comment: That blog post is from 2009, no longer relevant. That said, you can't import `_multiprocessing` because it isn't supported on App Engine. Why are you trying to use it?

Comment: @bossylobster to load an image from the Blobstore with BlobReader using `value = blob_reader.read()` but without having to block.

Comment: There isn't really any way to do this, but you may be able to use `ndb` [futures](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#urlfetch) to do something close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I am still trying to see how it would work.

Comment: you should update your question to state why you need to use multiprocessing module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/TpIUau1Ikp8/4A9fK_DbodgJ), one of the Python 2.7 App Engine runtime engineer point out to alternatives (namely the [futures](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) package) that should work with the new Python 2.7 [threading support](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#The_Sandbox).

Alternatively you could use the [`fetch_data_async`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions#fetch_data_async) functions to read from a blob without blocking.

```
fetch_data_rpc = blobstore.fetch_data_async(...)
other_processing()
upload_url = fetch_data_rpc.get_result()
```

Comment: I have not verified it, but from the reading it looks like it should do the trick. Thanks.